# How to center vertically labels in a view

Tags: ios, swift, position, uilabel

I have 4 labels like this in a view:

[image]

The view hierarchy like this:

[image]

But if one of text in each label is empty, all of other labels should center vertically with the image.

For example: the `albumDataLabel.text` is empty, then `userNameLabel`, `albumNameLabel`, `albumLocationLabel` should center vertically with the image.

Somethings like this:

[image]

So how to do this, please point me to some approaches.

Comment: try to use stackview ...

Comment: My application is use for iOS7, could you have another way for me.

Comment: is there any height constraint for the view that contains labels???

Comment: No there is not height constraint for labels, just vertical spacing, leading space and trailing space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your 4 Labels are already in a view, you can set the labels' constraints to pin the first Label to the top, last Label the bottom and spacing in between to zero

Then select the view(withLabels) and your ImageView to align their vertical centers

Do not set a height value constraint for your labels nor the view

When one of your labels have an empty string, the height is automatically set to zero and hence 'hidden' so the view(withLabels) will shrink in height. All can be done in the interface builder, no coding necessary, it is just a matter of autolayout.

Comment: So I don't need to set height constraint for each label like the answer above, right?

Comment: As far as how my testing for your question turned out, no height constraint is needed

Comment: Yes, no need. I have tried and it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

- Set height constraint for every label and which label have not text
  make it's height zero(from outlet of height constraint by setting constant to 0) at runtime.
- Your constraint should be in linear hierarchy like first label's top should be pinned with it's supper view's top and last label's bottom should be pinned with superview's bottom and each and every label's bottom should be pinned with top of below label.
- then you should set height constraint for `view` that contains all labels with constant `(>=)` of minimum height(least height of your view).
- and centered vertically that view with your image view.

you can do this kind of setup!!

Comment: I think I don't need to set height constraint for each label. It also works for me.

Comment: yeah you can do it without height constraint also then whole setup will be little bit different. I have suggest one possibility, it can be achieved by many way.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot @Ketan Parmar.

Answer (score 0):

1) for your *userNameLabel*:

```
userNameLabel.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(imageView.rightAnchor, constant: 10).active = true
                userNameLabel.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.topAnchor, constant: 50).active = true
                userNameLabel.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(220).active = true
                userNameLabel.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(30).active = true
```

2) for your *albumNameLabel*:

```
albumNameLabel.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(220).active = true
                albumNameLabel.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(30).active = true
                albumNameLabel.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(userNameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).active = true
                albumNameLabel.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(imageView.leftAnchor, constant: 10).active = true
```

3) remember this:

```
self.addSubview(userNameLabel)
self.addSubview(albumNameLabel)
```

And go on in this way to all elements in your View.